# How to display query output in below format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to display the output in the below format but ends up as below.

Actual Output required.

```
[               name
 -------------------------------------- 
|          Harry Potter               |
|          Ron Weasley                |
|          Hermione Granger           |
|          Albus Dumbledore           |
|          Severus Snape              |
]
```

[Screen capture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLml4.png)

I got the output as below:

```sql
'select '|'+ right('          '+name,30)+replicate(' ',20) +'|' 
from [sampleDB_for excercise].dbo.plch_characters
;'
```

```
[           name
|              Harry Potter                    |
|              Ron Weasley                    |
|              Hermione Granger                    |
|              Albus Dumbledore                    |
|              Severus Snape                    |
]
```

[Screen capture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmsfH.png)

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Also, I don't understand the question you were asking here. You need to explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have equal space in right you need to subtract length of the column from 20.

```
'select '|'+ right('          '+name,30)+replicate(' ',20-len(name)) +'|' 
from [sampleDB_for excercise].dbo.plch_characters
;'
```

To get the column name with equal spacing:

```
'select '|'+ right('          '+name,30)+replicate(' ',20-len(name)) +'|' as '|          name                |'
from [sampleDB_for excercise].dbo.plch_characters    ;'
```